# set pastetoggle not working

Tags: vim, osx-snow-leopard, iterm

My vim setup( https://github.com/aaronjorbin/.vim ) contains `set pastetoggle=<F2>` yet fn+F2 (when vim is running in terminal) causes vim to enter insert mode and output a `Q`  on it's own line (same behavior when I am already in insert mode).  This is the same if I am working on my local machine or if I have sshed into another server.

In iterm2, nothing happens when I am in normal or visual mode.  When I am in insert mode, `<F2>` is inserted.

My config works perfectly well on my mac mini and linux netbook, but this is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely due to your TERM type being set to something other than xterm xterm-color or xterm-256color.  I had mine set to linux for some reason I can't remember.  This caused the function keys to send escape sequences instead of being interpreted as function key presses. ie- F2 was sending `^[OQ` instead of `<F2>`.

If you need that terminal type you can change your .vimrc to use the key you want by pressing `<ctrl-v><F2>` in place of typing `<F2>`

The easier fix is of course to just change your terminal type to something that allows vim to work without jumping through hoops.

Comment: I have the TERM properly set to xterm (I use t_Co=256), this problem doesn't occur in my server which also has the TERM env variable as xterm.

Comment: FYI - Function keys also work with `TERM=gnome-256color`

Answer (score 4):

You have `set noesckeys` in your vimrc.

I've read a long time ago (no source, sorry) something about function keys being interpreted as `<Esc>number` in some terminals (`<Esc>9` for `<F9>`).

If I'm correct and if I read `:help noesckeys` correctly, `set noesckeys` is blocking all function keys. Try commenting it out.

Comment: Commenting that out doesn't seem to have made a difference.  Still exhibiting the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

(Very late answer I know but someone else may find this useful)

I encountered the same problem (Vim7.4 on OSX10.9.5) and what worked for me was to set pastetoggle *after* setting nocompatible (nocp).

Answer (score 0):

I found that on Macs the F2 key is mapped to "Turn Do Not Disturb On/Off". You can disable this setting under System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control. Uncheck the checkbox or pick another key. Picture below[image]