# vim on mac os X function key mapping not working

Tags: macos, vim

I have recently started using a Mac OS X Lion system and tried to use Vim in terminal. I previously had a .vimrc file in my Ubuntu system and had <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd> keys mapped to pastetoggle and run python interpreter. Here are the two lines I have for it:

```
set pastetoggle=<F2>
map <buffer> <F5> :wa<CR>:!/usr/bin/env python % <CR>
```

It's working just fine in Ubuntu but no longer works in Mac. (The above two lines are in .vimrc under my home dir.) I have turned off the Mac specific functions in my preference so the function keys are not been used for things like volume. Right now pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> seems to capitalize all letters until next word, and <kbd>F2</kbd> seems to delete next line and insert O.....

Is there something else I need to do to have it working as expected?

In addition, I had been using solarized as my color scheme and tried to have the same color scheme now in Mac. It seems that the scheme command is being read from .vimrc, but the colors are stil the default colors. Even though the .vim/colors files are just the same as before. Is this a related error that I need to fix? Perhaps another setting file being read after my own? (I looked for _vimrc and .gvimrc, none exists.)

Thanks!

Comment: It may or may not solve your problem, but you may want to try using [MacVim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) rather than Vim in Terminal.

Comment: @icktoofay hmm, I guess I had too high of an expectation of the "UNIX core" under OSX, lots of things actually have to be Mac specific. I will give MacVim a spin then.

Comment: It's not a difference with the "UNIX core", but rather with Terminal. If you use `xterm` then it should work as it did on Linux, but `xterm` isn't OS X-native; it has to run under the X11 helper application.

Comment: This isn't much help, but it's working for me. I went to System Preferences -> Keyboard and checked "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" (which it sounds like you did), put your lines into my .vimrc, and now pressing F5 runs Python. I'm running under OS X 10.6.8 and vim 7.2.108.

Comment: @icktoofay that makes sense, I thought it had to be a problem that terminal isn't actually firing `<F5>` when it's pressed, but just couldn't find any way of fixing it.

Comment: @SSteve yeah, I did that already. That's really strange. Do you have the identical line for assigning `<F5>` in your vimrc file? (I'm running Lion, so that could be making the difference, although a really bizzarre one.)

Comment: Yes, my .vimrc contained exactly (and only) the two lines from your question. Maybe try putting something obvious at the end of your .vimrc file (like "help") to make sure your .vimrc file is getting loaded.

Comment: MacVim fixed both problems. although it is kind of annoying that I have to open another window.... =( good to go for now

Comment: When you're on the console your keyboard may not be sending Vim what you think it's sending. See my answer to this question for more details:

stackoverflow.com/questions/9950944/

Answer (score 4):

I finally got my function mappings working by resorting to adding mappings like this:

```
if has('mac') && ($TERM == 'xterm-256color' || $TERM == 'screen-256color')
  map <Esc>OP <F1>
  map <Esc>OQ <F2>
  map <Esc>OR <F3>
  map <Esc>OS <F4>
  map <Esc>[16~ <F5>
  map <Esc>[17~ <F6>
  map <Esc>[18~ <F7>
  map <Esc>[19~ <F8>
  map <Esc>[20~ <F9>
  map <Esc>[21~ <F10>
  map <Esc>[23~ <F11>
  map <Esc>[24~ <F12>
endif
```

Answers to these questions were helpful, if you need to verify that these escape sequences match your terminal's or set your own:

[mapping function keys in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519532/mapping-function-keys-in-vim)
[Binding special keys as vim shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950944/binding-special-keys-as-vim-shortcuts)

It probably depends on terminal emulators behaving consistently (guffaw), but @Mark Carey's suggestion wasn't enough for me (I wish it was so simple). With iTerm2 on OS X, I'd already configured it for `xterm-256color` and tmux for `screen-256color`, and function mappings still wouldn't work. So the `has('mac')` might be unnecessary if these sequences from iTerm2 are xterm-compliant, I haven't checked yet so left it in my own config for now.

You might want some `imap` versions too. Note that you shouldn't use `noremap` variants since you **do** want these mappings to cascade (to trigger whatever you've mapped `<Fx>` to).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your colorscheme/solarized question - make sure you set up Terminal (or iTerm2, which I prefer) with the solarized profiles available in the full solarized distribution that you can download here: http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/files/solarized.zip.

Then the only other issue you may run into is making sure you set your $TERM `xterm-256color` or `screen-256color` if you use screen or tmux.

You can take a look at my [dotfiles](https://github.com/prognostikos/dotfiles) for a working setup, but don't forget to setup your Terminal/iTerm color profiles as a first step.

Answer (score 1):

see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524999/210923

essentially changing my TERM type to xterm-256color allowed me to map the function keys properly.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in my vimrc to copy and paste

```
if &term =~ "xterm.*"
    let &t_ti = &t_ti . "\e[?2004h"
    let &t_te = "\e[?2004l" . &t_te
    function XTermPasteBegin(ret)
        set pastetoggle=<Esc>[201~
        set paste
        return a:ret
    endfunction
    map <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin("i")
    imap <expr> <Esc>[200~ XTermPasteBegin("")
    cmap <Esc>[200~ <nop>
    cmap <Esc>[201~ <nop>
endif
```

I got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053522