# Vim mappings not working in OS X

Tags: macos, vim, vi

I have the following lines in my .vimrc for Ubuntu. They insert the current date as a string, and insert my signature at the bottom of the currently open file, respectively:

```
:map <F2> "=strftime("%B %d, %Y")<CR>Pli<Return><Esc>"
:map <F3> :e ~/.sign.txt<CR>ggV/^$<CR>k"*xG$a<C-R><C-O>*<Esc>:w<CR>:bd<CR>G$a<C-M><Esc>"*P
```

They're not working on my Macbook, though. The F2 command results in inserting "Q\n", and the F3 command results in inserting "R\n". How can I update these mappings to work on my Mac?

Comment: Terminal.app? By default the function keys aren't all bound the same as would be expected in other terminals. See https://github.com/google/terminal-app-function-keys

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/12814727/5591038. It might give you a pointer on how to use function keys with VIM on mac. I believe after the mappings specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12814727/5591038, you would be able to use your regular <F2>, <F3> mappings. Please give it a try.